# Unable to start debugging. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, startup

I have a solution and there are 2 projects inside of it. When I set the startup project to multiple start (because I'm using web services) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m68Ry.png) and when I click start, it says like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Zcg.png) "Unable to start debugging". I already checked the other related problem but nothing fixed it. Please any help?

I want to start the projects together (startup multiple)